# Not able to install any package from command prompt using pip

Tags: python, pip, operating-system

I'm trying to install any package using `pip` but it shows this:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\google-oauthlib-tool.exe' -> 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\google-oauthlib-tool.exe.deleteme'
```

Trying to install package.

Comment: Are there any files in the directory `C:\Python311\Scripts\google-oauthlib-tool.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

You should run this **as an Administrator**:

```bash
pip install numpy --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying the installation may help?

```
pip uninstall google-oauthlib-tool
pip install google-oauthlib-tool
```